# Android function is not being called

Tags: java, android, function

This function in my fragment is being called by another function that is called when a button is clicked. `getGridVals()` is called in my `calculate()` function in the beginning, but nothing is outputted in the `Log` from `getGridVals()` like it should be.
Only the `Log.v("test", "HI");` is outputted
However, in my `calculate()` function, the `Log` values are outputted.

```
public void calculate(){ 
    int[][] pegs = new int[3][3];
    getGridVals();// this is not working

////////This loop isnt working either for some reason, its just not even outputting anything
    for(int i=1;i<9;i++)
        Log.e("etC", etCollectionB[i]);

    int k=0;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            if(etCollectionB[k].equals(""))
                pegs[i][j] = 0;
            else
                pegs[i][j] = Integer.valueOf(etCollectionB[k]);
            Log.e("Value", String.valueOf(pegs[i][j]));
            k++;
        }

}
```

---

```
 public boolean getGridVals(){



        for(int i=1;i<9;i++)
        {
            EditText tempText1 = new EditText(mContext);
            tempText1.setText((CharSequence) mGrid.getItemAtPosition(i));
                    //this doesn't output
            Log.v("temp text ", tempText1.getText().toString());
                    //this outputs 
                    Log.v("test", "HI");



        }

        //this too doesnt output
        Log.d("et collection 1", String.valueOf(etCollectionB[1]));
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        {
            etCollectionB[i] = (String) mGrid.getItemAtPosition(i);
            Log.e("etCollectionB", etCollectionB[i]);


        }
            return true;
        //return false;
        //return etCollectionB;
    }
```

Comment: First off all, it returns Boolean value, so the right way to call the function should be: boolean b=getGridVals();
And second, do these functions/methods belong to the same class?

Comment: Check my edit, calling the function proper way should do it.

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild?

Comment: @DmitryKvochkin whether you assign the returned value or not makes no difference.

Comment: @DmitryKvochkin I tried that, it didn't work

Comment: @assylias yes, that still didn't help

Comment: @assylias i updated my calculate function, and it seems to not output anything related to etCollectionB[] for some reason

Comment: what does "loop isn't working" mean? It throws an exception? It gets bypassed? It crashes the app? It refuses to pick up a shovel after 6pm?  The only way that loop can not "work" is if you're not filtering your log message correctly and simply not seeing it. Or it dies on a null pointer. There's nothing else it could do.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel it seems to be getting bypassed because I don't see it in the logcat

Comment: I feel like your calculate function is not the one being called. Put debug statements at the start of every one of the functions you expect to be called, then trace through it to see where they stop.

Comment: @Eric my calculate function is being called because I see the log statements in it being outputted

Comment: do you try calling different method inside the calculate instead of gridVal?

Comment: @rasen58 Are you *sure* those log outputs are from *that* method? You have no method that would output something similar? Having two loops, where one executes but the one before it does not, makes absolutely no sense. I mean... see for yourself: http://ideone.com/NEWNUX

Comment: @Eric Ok, the function is being called and I updated my code, but only my new Log message is being outputted, the one i want to be outputted isn't though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh wow, I figured it out. It was such a stupid mistake. It was because there were nothing being retrieved from `tempText1.getText().toString(),` so the Log didn't even appear because there was nothing to output. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Funny--this had come to mind, but you had written at one point that `String.valueOf(9)` was also printing nothing in the log. Glad you figured it out, though! :)

Comment: Yea, sorry, I thought i didn't see the `String.valueOf(9)` but it was because i didnt scroll all the way down. I figured it out after doing `Log.v("test", "." + tempText1.getText().toString());`
It only printed out the "."